# Offer ram or silver?

Tags: leviticus, offering

In Leviticus 5:15 (NASB)

> “If a person acts unfaithfully and sins unintentionally against the Lord’s holy things, then he shall bring his guilt offering to the Lord: a ram without defect from the flock, according to your assessment in silver by shekels, in terms of the shekel of the sanctuary, as a guilt offering.

Could the offer be silver that matched the value of the ram?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could the offer be silver that matched the value of the ram?

No, because blood is necessary.

> Leviticus 5:14 The Lord said to Moses: 15“When anyone is unfaithful to the Lord by sinning unintentionally in regard to any of the Lord’s holy things, they are to bring to the Lord as a penalty a **ram** from the flock, one without defect and of the proper value in silver, according to the sanctuary shekel.  It is a guilt offering. 16They must make restitution for what they have failed to do in regard to the holy things, pay an additional penalty of a fifth of its value and give it all to the priest. The priest will make atonement for them with the **ram as a guilt offering**, and they will be forgiven.

The priest had to slaughter the ram and perform the ceremony.

Leviticus 7:2

> The **guilt offering** is to be slaughtered in the place where the burnt offering is slaughtered, and its **blood** is to be splashed against the sides of the altar.

The ram's blood foreshadowed the blood of Jesus. It could not be substituted by silver.

Answer (score 0):

He has to offer the Ram and also the Silver, of the value of fifth of the value of the ram. This Silver is to be offered  as a monetary penalty for sin against the "Holy Things". (A 'thing' for a 'thing'). Ref: Levictus 24:20, Exodus 21:24

Comment: Your reference scriptures apply to something completely different. Please explain how those scriptures apply to a sacrifice.